# Unable to pass a hash and a string to a function, together in perl!

Tags: perl

I am basically trying to pass a string and a hash to a subroutine in perl.

```
sub coru_excel {
    my(%pushed_hash, $filename) = @_;
    print Dumper(%pushed_hash);
}
```

But it seems data is getting mixed up. The dumped data also includes the `$filename`. here is the output.

```
...................
$VAR7 = 'Address';
$VAR8 = [
          '223 VIA DE
................
        ];
$VAR9 = 'data__a.xls'     <----- $filename
$VAR10 = undef;
$VAR11 = 'DBA';
$VAR12 = [
           'J & L iNC
..................
         ];
```

Here is how I called the subroutine.

```
coru_excel(%hash, "data_".$first."_".$last.".xls");
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing we cover in _Intermediate Perl_. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arguments are passed to subroutines as one undifferentiated list.

One solution is to reverse the order of the arguments so that the scalar is first.

```
sub coru_excel {
    my($filename, %pushed_hash) = @_;
}

coru_excel("FILE_NAME", %hash);
```

Another approach is to pass the hash by reference:

```
sub coru_excel {
    my($pushed_hash_ref, $filename) = @_;
}

coru_excel(\%hash, "FILE_NAME");
```

Answer (score 6):

You could pass the hash as a reference:

```
sub coru_excel {
    my($pushed_hashref, $filename) = @_;
    print Dumper(%$pushed_hashref);
}

coru_excel(\%my_hash, $file);
```

Or you could give special treatment to the final argument before you initialize the hash:

```
sub coru_excel {
    my $filename = pop @_;
    my(%pushed_hash) = @_;
    print Dumper(%pushed_hash);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass the hash as a reference:

```
coru_excel(\%hash, "data_".$first."_".$last.".xls");
```

You use it like this:

```
sub coru_excel {
    my($pushed_hash_ref, $filename) = @_;
    my %pushed_hash = %{$pushed_hash_ref};

    print Dumper(%pushed_hash); # better: \%pushed_hash or $pushed_hash_ref
}
```

See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for a tutorial on references and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for further information.

`Dumper` also produces better usable information when you pass a hash (or array) reference.

Answer (score 3):

See also the related Perl FAQ.  From the command line:

```
perldoc -q pass
```

or

```
perldoc -q hash
```

Refer to [perlfaq7](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html): [How can I pass/return a {Function, FileHandle, Array, Hash, Method, Regex}?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-pass/return-a-%7BFunction,-FileHandle,-Array,-Hash,-Method,-Regex%7D?)

Answer (score 2):

A small program demonstrating how to do this using reference notation when passing the hash and shift in the subroutine to pull out the parameters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
sub coru_excel(%$);
my %main_hash = ('key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2');
my $first = "ABC";
my $last = "xyz";
coru_excel(\%main_hash, "data_" . $first . "_" . $last . ".xls");
exit;

sub coru_excel(%$)
{
    my %passed_hash = %{(shift)};
    my $passed_string = shift;
    print "%passed_hash:\n";
    for my $k (keys %passed_hash) {
        print "  $k => $passed_hash{$k}\n";
    }
    print "\$passed_string = $passed_string\n";
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is the function prototype serving any useful purpose in this example?